Can charnamrit ever become impure/apavitra?
In the chanakya neeti is is said
६. पाद्यपीतावशेषं च सन्ध्याशेषं तथैव च। श्वानमूत्रसमं तोयं पीत्वा चान्द्रायणं
(चाणक्यनीति १७। ११)
६. पैर धोने, सन्ध्या करने तथा पीनेसे शेष बचा हुआ जल
कुत्तेके मूत्रके समान अपवित्र होता है। उसे पी लेनेपर चान्द्रायण-व्रत करना चाहिय|

Water left after washing feet, doing sandhya and the water left after drinking the water from bottle is as impure as dogs urine.(Chan. Neeti 17.11)
If i accidentally drink water from charnamrit bottle itself(without touching my mouth)then the maha mahimamaya charnamrit is impure or pure?
because I cannot go to that place for a long time(almost an year)to get charnamrit again so please help me :(

I'll bounty (+150) him who gives a nice answer

Charanamrit will never become impure but its hard to find direct reference .. its like Ganga water in which people wash their feet and body but the water remains ever pure.

@Rickross you mean my charnamrit is yet pure?

Yes it is pure even now

@Rickross are you sure Ganga water yet remains pure?

Yes even after drinking it, bathing it it will always remain pure

@Rickross last question if we mix impure water in charnamrit then the impure water has become pure? Just like dirty water which enters ganges is called ganges?

Suppose you have a bottle of water and you pour few drops of charanamrit in the bottle then that will turn the whole bottle water pure like charanamrit  and the reverse is also possibly true

@Rickross Yes for some reverse can also be true I think it's upon one's belief on charnamrit power thank you for solving my doubts
